# Using Auth with table name other than users laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am using `Auth` to authenticate the users. but using other than `users` table.
And whenever i use this controller function. It displays table `users` doesnot exists.

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
 {
    $input=$request->all();
    $password=$input['password'];
    $name=$input['name'];

    if (Auth::attempt(['Name' => $name, 'Password' => $password]) ){
        return redirect()->intended('/quiz/home');
}   else 
  {
        return view('quiz.login')->with('message','Error logging in!');
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change table name in `config/auth.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

[here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/authentication-to-use-administrators-instead-of-users) you've got the answer

```
// in the config/auth.php chage
'model' => 'App\User',
'table' => 'users',
// to...
'model' => 'App\Administrator',
'table' => 'administrators',
```